# Error when calling web service with lots of data

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service that is hosted locally. My web.config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>      
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/WebServices/NavigationService.svc/"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService"
    contract="NavigationService.INavigationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService" />
</client>   
</system.serviceModel>
```

My service works fine if I pass in less then 8K of text. Anything more and I get the following error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'UpdateSiteMap'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 75, position 166
```

Can someone tell me how to increase the text quota? As you can see, I have it set to maximum integer size.

EDIT

After Tim's suggestion, here is my new Web.Config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>      
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/WebServices/NavigationService.svc/"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService"
    contract="NavigationService.INavigationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService" />
</client>
<services>
  <service name="Navigation.INavigationService">

    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService"
              contract="NavigationService.INavigationService"  />

  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Post your service config file - it looks like you need to increase the values there, not on your client.

Comment: You are showing config for client, does your server side also have same confing for maxBuffer, contentLength, messageSize etc?

Comment: Guys, my Service and my client are running under the same IIS application, so the web.config is the same for both.

Comment: What does the `<services>` section of the Web.config look like?

Comment: @Tim -- I don't think I have a services section. I do have a System.ServiceModel section though

Comment: @icemanind - Are you using .NET 4.0?  If so it sounds like you're running up against default endpoints/bindings...let me update my answer.

Comment: @icemanind - Take a look at my answer for two solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message and your description of the issue, you need to ensure that you have the same settings for your service, referencing the same defined binding in the `bindingConfig` attirbute of the `endpoint` element:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Navigation.INavigationService">
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService"
                contract="NavigationService.INavigationService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you're using .NET 4.0 and have not specified the service element, then you are using a default endpoint and default binding (which means your limited to 8192 for maxStringContentLength).  The easiest way to overcome this is to remove the `name` attribute from the binding section of your config - .NET will then use your definition as the default binding.  For example:

```
<binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" ....
```

Note no `name` attribute is set.

You may need to use option 1 in this case, or create a similar binding definition with no name, as I'm not 100% sure that default bindings are used for the clients; they definitely are for the service.

See [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) for more information on default bindings and endpoints.

**Additional Answer Based On Edit**

Try this:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/WebServices/NavigationService.svc/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="NavigationService.INavigationService" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationService" />
</client>
```

Delete the `<services>` section as the default endpoint mechanism for WCF 4.0 will handle that for you, and delete the `bindingConfiguration` attribute from the client endpoint.

Comment: I removed the name tag and added the <services> tag. Do I need to specify a maximum size somewhere though?

Comment: As long as the binding (with no name attribute) has the larger sizes defined, you should be ok.

Comment: @icemanind - Can you post the new Web.config please?  I'll take a look and respond.

Comment: Try removing the `bindingConfiguration` attributes for both client and service - that may be mucking things up (to be honest I'm surprised the service even ran with a reference to a non-existent binding configuration).  Also make sure the service name in the service section matches what is specified in your .svc file.

Comment: What happens in .NET 3.5? Does it have a default endpoint mechanism too?